# Colocar fecha de nacimiento en un input date html

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc

Les comento mi consulta. Estoy realizando un sistema en donde tengo gestion de usuarios. En un formulario registro los datos personales de los usuarios. Tambien tengo la opcion de modificar esos datos personales que ya fueron registrados. Y lo que necesito es que al ingresar a realizar la modificacion de los datos personales en el campo fecha de nacimiento poder asignarle la fecha de nacimiento anteriormente registrada en el calendario (input date). Lo realize de la siguiente manera y no puedo obtener ese dato.

Ese es el codigo de mi vista donde pueden ver lo que le asigno al elemento date pero no obtengo resultados.

```html
@model VacunAR.Models.Integrante
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ModificacionIntegrante</title>
    <link rel=StyleSheet href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel=StyleSheet href="~/Content/Background.css">
    <link rel=StyleSheet href="~/Content/Formulario.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="ModificacionIntegrante">
            <label> Id:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Id" value="@Model.Id" readonly />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> DNI:</label>
            <input type="text" name="DNI" value="@Model.DNI" readonly />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Apellido:</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido" value="@Model.Apellido" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Nombres:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" value="@Model.Nombre" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Tipo de Documento:</label>
            <input type="text" name="tipodocumento" value="@Model.TipoDocumento" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Nacionalidad:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nacionalidad" value="@Model.Nacionalidad" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
            <input type="date" name="fechanac" value="@Model.FechaNac" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Sexo:</label>
            <input type="text" name="sexo" value="@Model.Sexo" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Telefono:</label>
            <input type="text" name="telefono" value="@Model.Telefono" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="@Model.Email" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Modificar" />
        </form>
        <br />
        <a href="/Home/MenuIntegrantes" title="Volver al Menu Integrantes"><img src="~/Contenido/volver.png"></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

solo obtengo lo siguiente pero no sale la fecha de nacimiento registrada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
namespace VacunAR.Models
{
    public class Integrante
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DNI { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string TipoDocumento { get; set; }
        public string Nacionalidad { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaNac { get; set; }
        public char Sexo { get; set; }
        public long Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Publica tu clase VacunAR.Models.Integrante

Comment: publicada la clase Integrante

Comment: Por qué no estás utilizando los Html Helpers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que `FechaNac` es del tipo `DateTime` y tú tienes un input `date` si fuera `<input type="datetime">` te funcionaria. No existe el tipo `Date` en C#, la única manera es dar formato a la fecha para eliminar la componente Time. Para esto existen 2 formas:

**1.- Formatear en la Clase**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime FechaNac { get; set; }
```

Y luego poner

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaNac)
```

o en su lugar

```
<input asp-for="FechaNac" />
```

**2.- Formatear directamente en el input**

```
<input type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" asp-for="FechaNac" />
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Yussef. Muy buena explicacion y lo que me indicaste me sirvio, logre solucionar gracias a tu respuesta.